# How to make external program windows taller than screen size?

Tags: c#, window, size

How to make a external program windows taller than the screen height?

I have to adjust external program window height until it shows all the content. The reason is, those programs made for larger screens, but not fit on smaller screens. I can get handle to the program but do not know where to start from.

I tried to find some sample c# code using WM_GETMINMAXINFO but had no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with WM_SIZE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;
     MoveWindow(this.Handle , 0, 0, 1000, 1000, true);